# vb.NET DLL accessed via Com Interop on IIS - Where should config file be?

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis, dll

I have a legacy VB6 DLL used on IIS that now needs to access a VB.NET DLL

We have created the .NET DLL and it all works with another desktop VB6 application just fine via InterOp.

The .NET dll has a reference to a 3rd party webservice.

We have registered the .NET DLL using REGASM on the webserver,  however when we instantiate the DLL functions from the VB6 DLL we get a failure message,

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 
ServiceReference1.XXXX' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might
be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no 
endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

We have tried many different names for the config file,  have tried suggestions from SO such as setting the Application Root Directory in Component services for the VB6 DLL,  even back to adding DLLHost.exe.config file in the system root from Win2000 days,  doesn't seem to matter what we do, the DLL cant find its config

Layout of what we need for reference

.Net DLL -> vb6.DLL (on Component Services) -> IIS 7.5

I know this is a bit archaic, but our hands are tied on the VB6.DLL at the moment,  so we need to get this working

Comment: This isn't an `asp-classic` question - could you remove the tag please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,  figured this one out

I copied the config file to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe.config

All now works as expected,  my VB6 DLL can call the interop VB.NET DLL and it reads it's settings correctly